# How can I show the number of positions lines have moved in diff output?

Tags: bash, diff, csv

### top1

```
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,wikipedia.org
6,baidu.com
7,live.com
8,amazon.com
9,qq.com
10,twitter.com
```

### top2

```
1,facebook.com
2,google.com
3,youtube.com
4,yahoo.com
5,baidu.com
6,wikipedia.org
7,live.com
8,qq.com
9,amazon.com
10,twitter.com

diff -u  /Users/stofke/Desktop/top2a.csv /Users/stofke/Desktop/top1a.csv |
  sed -n '1,2d;/^[-+]/p' |
  sort --field-separator=',' --key=2 

+9,amazon.com
-8,amazon.com
+5,baidu.com
-6,baidu.com
+8,qq.com
-9,qq.com
+6,wikipedia.org
-5,wikipedia.org
```

But I actually need this:

```
 +1, amazon.com
 -1  baidu.com
 -1  qq.com
 +1  wikipedia.org
```

I don't know how to do that last step

(I would also need to calculate the % wise decline or raise)

Adding `|  paste -d, - -`

gets me this

```
+9,amazon.com,-8,amazon.com
+5,baidu.com,-6,baidu.com
+8,qq.com,-9,qq.com
+6,wikipedia.org,-5,wikipedia.org
```

Comment: Diff doesn't do this. You'll need to write a small script that does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also consider an approach using `join` since you want sorted output in the end. Like:

```
join -t, -j2 <(sort -t, -k2 file1) <(sort -t, -k2 file2) |
   awk -F, '{n=$3-$2; if (n) print n, $1}'
```

Comment: I like this answer, it's easy to read and does it well

Answer (score 4):

Using awk

```
awk -F, '
    NR == FNR {n[$2] = $1; next}
    {n[$2] -= $1}
    END {for (k in n) if (n[k] != 0) printf " %2d  %s\n",n[k],k}
' top1 top2
```

outputs

```
 -1  amazon.com
  1  qq.com
 -1  wikipedia.org
  1  baidu.com
```

order not guaranteed.

Comment: I bet it's good but it's too hard for me to read it and understand it.  Anyway thank you very much for this answer